# How to programmatically save text as image file in Objective-c?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, image, text

I want am working on a project where I need to save user typed text as .PNG file through objective-c. I mean when user typed some text I give option to the user to choose font type then save it. After that the file will be saved as .PNG file without background.

How can I achieve this. Please share your views.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use this method get image from text:

```
-(UIImage *)imageFromText:(NSString *)text
{
// set the font type and size
//UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:txtView.font];  
CGSize size  = [text sizeWithFont:txtView.font]; // label or textview

// check if UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions is available (iOS is 4.0+)
if (UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions != NULL)
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(size,NO,0.0);
else
    // iOS is < 4.0 
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(size);

 [text drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,size.width,size.height) withFont:txtView.font]; 
 UIImage *testImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();    
 return testImg;
}
```

Now u have image save like this

```
NSString *docDir = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0];

NSString *pngFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/test.png",docDir]; // any name u want for image
NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImagePNGRepresentation(image)]; your image here
[data1 writeToFile:pngFilePath atomically:YES];
```